# azure servicebus how to do incremental production deployment

Tags: azure, servicebus

I'd like to know what is the best practice for doing incremental production deployment in azure with servicebus,

- How to ensure that the messages don't get deleted when deploying a new version
- Is there a backup mechanism to save the messages and load it back after the deployment is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Azure Service Bus is a service which runs outside of your deployment, similar to Windows Azure SQL Database or Windows Azure Storage. This means that it does not depend on your deployment: you can deploy, remove, re-deploy your application without impacting the messages present in the Service Bus.

The only thing you'll need to take care of when you deploy a new version of your application is that the messages available in Service Bus Queues / Subscriptions might have been sent by the old version of the application. So take into account that the new version of your application will need to be compatible with these "old" message formats.